# Add array to Object

Tags: javascript

I have a collection of inputs

```html
<input type="text" name="item" id="item" value="Name">  
<input type="number" name="unit_price" id="unit_price" value="100">
<input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="2">
<input type="number" name="discount" id="discount" value="0">
<input type="text" name="item" id="item" value="Name 2">  
<input type="number" name="unit_price" id="unit_price" value="200">
<input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="5">
<input type="number" name="discount" id="discount" value="10">
```

I'm trying to loop through all of these inputs to create an object with keys exactly the same as names in my inputs and add those values as values.
So my steps are:

```js
let arr = []
inputs.forEach((elem) => {
  console.log(elem.value)
  arr.push({
    'item': elem.value,
    'unit_price': elem.value,
    'qty': elem.value,
    'discount': elem.value
  });
})
```

**EDITED**
the expected output should look like this:

```js
arr = [{
    'item': 'Name',
    'unit_price': '100',
    'qty': '2',
    'discount': '0',
  },
  {
    'item': 'Name 2',
    'unit_price': '200',
    'qty': '5',
    'discount': '10'
  }
]
```

Comment: Aside: you can't have elements with the same ids. Ids must be unique (just one per page).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the input elements in chunks of 4.

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
let res = [];
let names = ['item', 'unit_price', 'qty', 'discount'];
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += names.length)
  res.push(names.reduce((acc, curr, j) => (acc[curr] = inputs[i + j].value, acc), {}));
console.log(res);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="item" id="item" value="Name">
<input type="number" name="unit_price" id="unit_price" value="100">
<input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="2">
<input type="number" name="discount" id="discount" value="0">
<input type="text" name="item" id="item" value="Name 2">
<input type="number" name="unit_price" id="unit_price" value="200">
<input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="5">
<input type="number" name="discount" id="discount" value="10">
```

Comment: Really close to want I need. Two objects should look like this
res = [{
'item': 'Name', 
'unit_price': '100',
'qty': '2',
'discount':'0'
},
{
'item': 'Name 2', 
'unit_price': '200',
'qty': '5',
'discount':'10'
}]

Comment: @StanislavShokarev I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two separate objects, you can add a class to the inputs to group them like so.

```html
<input class="item1" type="text" name="item" id="item" value="Name">  
<input class="item1" type="number" name="unit_price" id="unit_price" value="100">
<input class="item1" type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="2">
<input class="item1" type="number" name="discount" id="discount" value="0">

<input class="item2" type="text" name="item" id="item2" value="Name 2">  
<input class="item2" type="number" name="unit_price" id="unit_price2" value="200">
<input class="item2" type="number" name="qty" id="qty2" value="5">
<input class="item2" type="number" name="discount" id="discount2" value="10">
```

Then, for the javascript, because you are wanting to turn an array of items into a single object, this is a good candidate to use a reduce!

```js
function aggrigateInputs(className) {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className)

  return elements.reduce((acc, elem) => {
    acc[elem.name] = elem.value;

    return acc;
  }, {})
}

const item1 = aggrigateInputs('item1');
const item2 = aggrigateInputs('item2');

console.log(item1, item2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you can wrap your inputs inside divs, and then find each block of values and map the values into two objects. Like:

```
  <div id="first">
    <input type="text" name="item" id="item" value="Name">  
    <input type="number" name="unit_price" id="unit_price" value="100">
    <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="2">
    <input type="number" name="discount" id="discount" value="0">
  </div>

  <div id="second">
    <input type="text" name="item" id="item" value="Name 2">  
    <input type="number" name="unit_price" id="unit_price" value="200">
    <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="5">
    <input type="number" name="discount" id="discount" value="10">
  </div>
```

And in JS

```
      const first = {}
      const second = {}
      document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach( input => {
        if (input.parentElement.id === 'first') {
          first[input.name] = input.value;
        } else {
          second[input.name] = input.value;
        }
      });
      console.log(first, second);
```